# What is the basis that allows a judge to reject a defense in a criminal trial in the USA

Tags: court, trial

I have another question inspired from watching *Law and Order*.

Often, a defense attorney will give notice of a defense, and both the defense lawyer and prosecutor will be in the Judges chambers making their arguments, with the judge deciding if they allow the defense or not.

Why does a judge have this power? What is the basis in law?

Why is a defense attorney not free to use whatever defense they feel best serves their clients?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A judge has the authority to determine what law applies to a case and to instruct the jury accordingly, and also has the authority to determine which evidence is admissible.

Presentation of a defense, in practice, involves presentation of evidence supporting a legal theory.

In order to be admissible in evidence in an evidentiary hearing or trial, the evidence must be relevant to a legal theory that is in some way connected to the evidence. If no reasonable juror could make a ruling establishing that a legally recognized defense was established based upon the proposed evidence (especially if the proposed evidence is prejudicial to the prosecution case on the basis of reasoning that is not a legally valid defense) it can be excluded.

For example, evidence in support of the theory that the defendant murdered the victim because the murder victim raped the defendant's sister six years ago, might very well sway a jury to acquit the defendant. So a defense attorney might want to make this argument. But, this is not a legally recognized justification for murder, so evidence in support of this defense would be excluded as irrelevant by the judge.

In federal court, and in states with rules of evidence based upon the federal rules of evidence, the primary legal authority behind this is Rule of Evidence 402:

> Rule 402. General Admissibility of Relevant Evidence
>
> Relevant evidence is admissible unless any of the following provides
>   otherwise:
>
> the United States Constitution; a federal statute; these rules; or
>   other rules prescribed by the Supreme Court.
>
> Irrelevant evidence is not admissible.

Some states also have procedural notice requirements for certain kinds of affirmative defenses.

For example, if someone is arguing an alibi, a notice of an intent to present this defense must be provided by the defense a certain number of days before trial, so that the prosecution can develop the very different in kind type of evidence needed to rebut that defense, rather than having someone acquitted due to surprise when rebuttal evidence exists but the prosecution doesn't know in advance to locate the necessary witnesses and evidence to rebut this kind of defense.

Comment: Ah, very clear answer, thank you! So essentially it comes down to allowing or disallowing the evidence, since the defense will stem from that?

Comment: Is there (I honestly don't know) also some notion that it's the judge's responsibility to oversee that the lawyer actually *is* representing their client's best interests? As in, it's going to save the whole legal system a bunch of trouble in a later "ineffective assistance of counsel" proceeding if the judge, here, can serve as a second set of eyes to ensure that someone's not just mailing it in? Or is that not part of a judge's portfolio?

Comment: In the first case, that would be an unwise judge, mainly because the defendant cannot be prevented from testifying. If the jury gets one whiff there was evidence the defense wanted to present but couldn't, it's over.

Comment: "defendant murdered the victim because the murder victim raped the defendant's sister" - on L&O in chambers, they're usually arguing about whether someone's *testimony* is relevant as *evidence*, not the whole 'defense' (unless it is, and it always is because: drama). And then if 'oops', "the jury will disregard" and if it's bad enough then "mistrial" which while in chambers they were warned would happen should they pursue that line of questioning.

Comment: A major problem with the notion of "relevance" is that there is no particular set of rules juries are supposed to follow when assessing witness credibility, and thus often no way of determining whether a piece of evidence might reasonably affect such assessments.  If the defendant doesn't have particular evidence of innocence, the prosecution witness would have an unusually string motive to make a false accusation, evidence of such motives may not be directly relevant to the factual matter of the defendant's guilt, but could substantially increase the level of reasonable doubt.

Comment: @supercat Another rule of evidence with mountains of case law to clarify it defines 'relevance". The definition is normative and not descriptive. Evidence is relevant is it would be in a sincere juror acting rationally, even if other evidence would influence someone.

Comment: @nitsua60 "Is there (I honestly don't know) also some notion that it's the judge's responsibility to oversee that the lawyer actually is representing their client's best interests?" Generally not in the proceeding in which the inferior lawyering is taking place. The full answer is a bit more complicated and something I am not at liberty to write about as it is one of the issues pending in a legal malpractice case where I represent one of the parties.

Comment: @ohwilleke: Unfortunately, it would often be impossible to apply such a definition of relevance without making factual determinations, and factual determinations are supposed to be the job of the jury.  As a simple example, suppose that a witness answers questions so evasively that it's doubtful that any reasonable juror would believe their accusations, but the defense wants to introduce evidence that the witness would have a motive to lie.  Should such evidence be "relevant"?  It might sway an unreasonable juror toward a correct decision, but it a reasonable juror should...

Comment: ...reach the correct decision with or without that evidence, one could argue that it would be "irrelevant" because it couldn't affect a reasonable juror.  If, however, the evidence is suppressed and the accused is convicted because jurors thought "the witness had no reason to lie", however, viewing the evidence of such motive as "irrelevant" would seem disingenuous.

Comment: @supercat There is also a rule of evidence about making factual determinations necessary to rule on rule of evidence disputes. Rule 401 defines relevant, Rules 103 and 104 are the main rules dealing with evidence about evidence admissibility.

Comment: @ohwilleke: One thing I'd like to see added as part of "preserving the record" for the appeals process would be a means by which a defendant could ask the jury to make particular factual findings beyond guilt or innocence, so that if e.g. a piece of evidence was suppressed as "irrelevant", but the jury's decision was based on a factual finding contrary to what it would have shown, an appeals court would not be entitled to presume that the evidence would not have affected the jury's decision.

Comment: @supercat The notion of a "special verdict" or "jury interrogatories" of the kind you mention aren't that uncommon in civil cases. They are allowed to a very limited extent in criminal cases but not for the purposes and in the manner that you suggest. There are reasons that the doctrine has evolved that way historically. The history is beyond the scope of a comment.